# Data for daterange is not same

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

i have problem with my sql.The problem is a result data  from the table is not same like i put in parameter.
can you check what's wrong with my code?.

This is my code:-

```
select distinct  convert(varchar(10),a.entered,103) as
daterange  from customer
where
((a.entered BETWEEN convert(varchar(10),&daterangefrom,103) AND convert(varchar(10),&daterangeto,103)) or (convert(varchar(10),&daterangefrom,103) =' ' AND convert(varchar(10),&daterangeto,103) =' '))
```

Comment: What is your expected result? what result your getting.

Comment: Is part of the query missing? Where is the alias `a` coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing the dates as strings, but the dd/mm/yyyy format that you are using doesn't work for such comparisons. For example, `'2/4/1976' > '1/9/2012'`.

Compare the dates as dates:

```
select distinct convert(varchar(10),a.entered,103) as daterange
from customer
where (
  (&daterangefrom = ' ' AND &daterangeto = ' ') or
  (a.entered BETWEEN &daterangefrom AND &daterangeto)
)
```

Alternatively, use the ISO 8601 based yyyy-mm-dd format, which does work as string comparisons:

```
select distinct convert(varchar(10),a.entered,103) as daterange
from customer
where (
  (a.entered BETWEEN convert(varchar(10),&daterangefrom,120) AND convert(varchar(10),&daterangeto,120)) or
  (&daterangefrom =' ' AND &daterangeto =' ')
)
```

Comment: that's my main problem. i want to key in data 01/01/2011 to 17/03/2011. but the error show  'The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.'

Comment: @Amin: Then you are converting in the wrong direction, as you are converting from a date to a string, not from a string to a date. Use `convert(datetime, &daterangefrom, 103)`.

Comment: @Amin - Why aren't you passing the value to the database as a date? Why not validate that it is a date before you try to execute your SQL statement?

Comment: @Amin - Also, that error is almost assuredly indicative of the database server having a different date ordering (MDY instead of DMY).

Comment: @Thomas: The error is because the string is implicitly converted to a date because the `convert` function expects a date to convert to a string. If you specify the date format in the `convert` call, it doesn't matter what the default date format is. Using `convert(datetime,&date,103)` will correctly convert a string in the format dd/mm/yyyy into a date.

Comment: @Guffa - True. But `Convert( varchar(10), @somevarcharval, 103 )` will simply pass the value through with no error. It is the use in comparison to a DateTime col that must trigger the conversion and the error.

Comment: This is my answer.select distinct  convert(varchar(10),a.entered,103) as
daterange  from customer a
where
((a.entered BETWEEN convert(datetime,&daterangefrom,103) AND convert(datetime,&daterangeto,103)) 
or (convert(datetime,&daterangefrom,103) =' ' AND convert(datetime,&daterangeto,103) =' '))

Comment: @Amin - Again, why are you making all these calls to `Convert`? Why not simply make your two parameters typed as DateTime and avoid that? Make it incumbent on the calling code to pass valid dates.

Comment: if user put the date time. User must put in format 10/6/2009 12:30:39 PM . That why i put the parameter as string

Comment: @Amin - Two choices: 1. Strip the time value from the date before passing it your query. 2. Strip the time value without converting it to a string by using a technique like I showed or a host of other approaches. E.g. `Cast( Floor( Cast( SomeDateValue as float ) ) As datetime )` is another way to do it.

Comment: @Amin - Btw, option #1, stripping the time value prior to passing it to SQL Server, is the better option.

Answer (score 3):

Check this, it works fine for me:

```
select distinct convert(varchar(10),a.entered,103) as daterange 
  from customer a 
 where ( ( a.entered BETWEEN convert(datetime,&daterangefrom,103) 
                         AND convert(datetime,&daterangeto,103) ) 
      or ( convert(datetime,&daterangefrom,103) = ' ' 
           AND convert(datetime,&daterangeto,103) = ' ' )
           )
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you are doing a bunch of conversions on the dates in order to extract the date portion from the time portion. There are faster and simpler methods. One method I use here is:

```
DateAdd( d, DateDiff( d, 0, SomeDateValue ), 0 )
```

This finds the number of days between the 0 date (1900-01-01) and `SomeDateValue` and then adds that many days to the 0 date producing a date value with a zero time portion. So, one solution, given what you have presented, would be:

```
Select Distinct DateAdd( d, DateDiff( d, 0, C.Entered ), 0 ) As [Date]
From customer As C
Where   (
        C.Entered >= DateAdd( d, DateDiff( d, 0, @DateRangeFrom ), 0 )
        And 
        C.Entered < DateAdd( d, DateDiff( d, 0, @DateRangeTo ), 1 )
        )
    Or ( @DateRangeFrom Is Null And @DateRangeTo Is Null )
```

In this solution, I used `>=` and `<` instead of `Between` so that I can add an extra day to the `@DateRangeTo` value and find all values strictly less than this end point. That ensures that if `@DateRangeTo` passes a time portion, that we use all values in that day up to and inlcuding `11:59:59`. If you know that you will always pass the two parameters with a zero time value, then you can simplify the query like so:

```
Select Distinct DateAdd( d, DateDiff( d, 0, C.Entered ), 0 ) As [Date]
From customer As C
Where   (
        C.Entered >= @DateRangeFrom
        And 
        C.Entered < DateAdd( d, 1, @DateRangeTo )
        )
    Or ( @DateRangeFrom Is Null And @DateRangeTo Is Null )
```

In addition, for some reason, you were comparing `@DateRangeFrom` and `@DateRangeTo` to an empty string. Presuming these are typed as `DateTime` as they should be, there is no need for that. Simply check whether the passed values are null.

Lastly, in any of the resulting Select statements, you can always use the `Convert` function on only the output.

```
Select Distinct Convert(varchar(10), DateAdd( d, DateDiff(d, 0, C.Entered), 0), 103)
```